# Polymer 1.0 - how to set icon position programmatically

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Using Polymer 1.0 and Dart, I have:

```
  PaperButton paperButtonForget = new PaperButton();
  IronIcon iconClear = new IronIcon();
  paperButtonForget.innerHtml = "Forget";
  paperButtonForget.children.add(iconClear);
  paperButtonForget.raised=true;
```

The button produced shows
"FORGET X"

I have 2 questions:

1) How can I make it show
"X FORGET"
as in 
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-button

2) paperButtonForget.raised=true;
"doesn't work" - but maybe I need to do something else...?

cheers
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you get the icon to the left and the button is shown raised:

```
import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'app_element.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_button.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/iron_icon.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/communication_icons.dart';

/// [AppElement]
main() async {
  await initPolymer();
  PaperButton paperButtonForget = new PaperButton();
  IronIcon iconClear = new IronIcon()..icon = 'communication:email';
  paperButtonForget.append(iconClear);
  paperButtonForget.append(new dom.Text("Forget"));
  paperButtonForget.attributes['raised']='true';
  dom.document.body.append(paperButtonForget);
}
```